# How can I make (Neo)Vim wrap lines in respect to indentation?

Tags: neovim, indentation, wrapping

Currently, indented lines will wrap all the way to the left of the text area. This is what they look like:

```
    This is a long line of text that is indented wi
th tabs. In order for it to properly fit inside the
 screen, it must be wrapped.
```

I'd rather have them wrap to the end of indentation, like this:

```
    This is a long line of test that is indented wi
    th tabs. In order for it to properly fit inside
    the screen, it must be wrapped.
```

Using NeoVim v0.9.1, **how?**

Comment: See `:h 'breakindent'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable this feature, you can add the following line to your (Neo)Vim configuration file, typically located at `~/.vimrc` for Vim or `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` for Neovim:

```
set breakindent
```

If you'd like to enable this just for the current session, you can run the command:

```
:set breakindent
```

in command mode.

---

You can also customize the behavior further with the breakindentopt option. For example, to set an additional indent for wrapped lines, you could use:

```
set breakindentopt=shift:2
```

This would add an extra 2 spaces of indentation to each wrapped line. You can replace 2 with your preferred number of spaces.

Remember to reload your configuration file after editing it or restart (Neo)Vim to apply the changes.